# Command Line Arguments (Strings) from textfile for C-Program

Tags: c, overflow

I have a c programm, which needs two arguments (strings).
My problem is I need to do an overflow and one argument needs to be 66000 chars long.

So I have a textfile which contains a 66000 chars long string. **But how do I pass this string from the file do the c program as an argument?**

I already tried: myprog < textFile

But this does not work

OS: Ubuntu.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better suited for unix.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a bash question.

If you call:

```
myprog < textFile
```

you don't pass textFile as argument, so your c program won't find any argument in `char *argv[]`. Instead `STDIN` is taken to come from `textFile`. Of course you could just read the file content from there, but I understand, you exactly want to pass it as one argument.

So you would call:

```
myprog "$(cat textFile)"
```